# easyvideoplayer-0.3.0 Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, android-studio

I am stuck into one problem in android
Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/com/afollestad/easyvideoplayer/0.3.0/easyvideoplayer-0.3.0.aar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Comment: where you got this problem, like while configuration, compilation etc.

Comment: yes, Previously it is working fine but now I get this with same code